# Pass array with data to ChoiceType (html select) in Symfony v4.2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, select, symfony4

### Introduction

For my personal project i use

- Symfony v4.2
- PHP 7.2.12

### Problem

I can not figure out how to make `ChoiceType` element display `IDs` and `EMAILs` as `HTML SELECT` option *values* and *indexes*.

### Example

The picture displays current state of `html select`  with data (`id` and `email`) from database.

[image: The picture displays current state of `thml select with data from database]

### Code

> Array of data from database `($this->userChoices)`

```
array:4 [
    0 => array:2 [
        "id" => 7
        "email" => "1st@example.com"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
        "id" => 8
        "email" => "2nd@example.com"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [
        "id" => 5
        "email" => "3rd@example.com"
    ]
    3 => array:2 [
        "id" => 6
        "email" => "4th@example.com"
    ]
]
```

> What i am getting

```
<select id="my-select" name="my-select" class="form-control">
    <optgroup label="0">
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="1st@example.com">1st@example.com</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="1">
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="2nd@example.com">2nd@example.com</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="2">
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="3rd@example.com">3rd@example.com</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="3">
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="4th@example.comm">4th@example.com</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

> What i want to get

```
<select id="my-select">
    <option value=""> Please choose an option </option>
    <option value="7">1st@example.com</option>
    <option value="8">2nd@example.com</option>
    <option value="5">3rd@example.com</option>
    <option value="6">4th@example.com</option>
</select>
```

> Relevant part of `myChoiceType`

```
->add('selectUser', ChoiceType::class,
    [
        'choices' => $this->userChoices,
        'choice_value' => function ($choice)
        {
            return $choice;
        },
        'choice_label' => function ($value)
        {
            return $value;
        },
        'mapped' => false,
        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => false,
    ]
)
```

### Finally

What am i doing wrong?

How to get `ChoiceType` display `data` in `html select` in the manner i want it to?

Thank you for ideas!

Comment: Hello, @Jeto! it is already displayed in first code block. I clarified the heading of the code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices), the `choices` value must be a simple key => value array.

> The choices option is an array, where the array key is
>   the item's label and the array value is the item's value

You can easily get the choices array you want using this code:

```
$choices = [];
foreach ($this->userChoices as $choice) {
  $choices[$choice['email']] = $choice['id'];
}
```

Then use the following initialization code:

```
->add('selectUser', ChoiceType::class,
    [
        'choices' => $choices,
        'mapped' => false,
        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => false
    ]
)
```

Not that I removed `choice_value` and `choice_label` which don't serve any purpose in this case.

Comment: Hey @Jeto! I used your code in the controller before passing data array to the form, but i am getting a notice `Notice: Undefined index: 1st@example.com`

Comment: @Rikijs Sorry I messed up the code. Should be better now! (edited the answer)

Comment: Thank you @Jeto, now it works! Just exchanged `id` ad `email` to suite my needs - so email is displayed and value is id.

Comment: @Rikijs Oh you're right, I just edited again, I mixed them both up (but it was enough to give you the idea). Should be good now.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass it as a one dimensional array, with emails as keys, and ids as values.

```
$choices = [
    '1st@example.com' => 7,
    '2nd@example.com' => 8,
];
```